# How enable Viber backup on iPad?

Tags: ipad, backup

Viber allows to enabled backup on a main device — on a phone device, by default.
But when you installed it on iPad (or another tablet) only (let's say you don't have smartphone), will backup be available?

If so, how to make Viber switch iPad to the main device? (Viber uninstall on the iPhone does not help)

Comment: Have you tried asking on their Support pages?

Comment: Well, that's not a thing when you can talk to a community. Yes, that's still an option, but it's too official at this stage. Maybe later. I guess, here will be no luck with kind of tricky apple-question.